# Punishments for a soldier who kills another soldier in unintentional friendly fire

Tags: halacha, army-military-war, murder

An IDF Soldier is returning to base, and a sniper on guard sees the IDF soldier. He sees the IDF soldier he thinks the person is Hamas. He then shoots the IDF Soldier in defense of the base.

Under halachic law, if you kill someone in friendly fire, does it count as murder? What punishment would this man be given?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.22.1-2

Comment: Related (esp. what Rabbi Elyashiv said): https://archive.jdn.co.il/beit_hamidrash/614782/

Comment: Isn't it more similar to an accidental murderer (the sniper thought he was firing at someone else, an enemy) than to a rodef (where the one killing a rodef has explicit intent to kill him in particular)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [shiur](https://youtu.be/f-EuWAGxpRY?t=1394), Rav Asher Weiss shlit"a rules that in cases of "friendly fire" the soldier does not have to do teshuva.